# Inject a dependency outside of a component

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement a service that will help to inject dependencies from anywhere of the application:

```
import { Injectable, ReflectiveInjector } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class AppInjector {

    constructor() {
    }

    public static inject<T>(i: {new(): T; }): T {
      return ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([i]).get(i);
    }
}
```

And while I am injecting a service (well annotated with `@Injectable()`) I use it like this:

```
myService : MyService = AppInjector.inject<MyService>(MyService);
```

This code is not working, for I am getting a `null` value for `myService`. Do you an explanation why this isn't working?

Comment: Why use this instead of 'standard' Angular injection?

Comment: Your code creates an injector that has only `i` as registered provider and therefore `i` will be all that you can inject. I strongly suggest to just drop the entire idea and use Angulars DI as it is intended (or alternatively rather not use Angular instead of trying to misuse it this way)

Comment: @RichardMatsen Matsen The class where I need to inject `MyService` is used as a simple model. Standard injection using the class constructor will affect the parameters that I use to initialize this model, where my need to inject the service outside of the constructor

Comment: Ok. It appears there's no dependencies to resolve - why not use new() inside the modal?

Comment: @RichardMatsen My bad, I was calling the `myService` instance from a method that was called by a prototype and not an instance of my model. Both the `AppInjector.inject()` and the `new()` work, but what's the best practice?